# jQuery - simplifying code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to simplify the jQuery coding necessary to render this action. I want to have a set of 4 links where one link is hidden based upon the appropriate page that it is on. So if I were on page 1, I would want to hide link 1 and yet keep links 2,3 and 4 visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/chapster82/k43a8/

Thanks for any help.

HTML

```
<div class="links" id="div1">A</div>
<div class="links" id="div2">B</div>
<div class="links" id="div3">C</div>
<div class="links" id="div4">D</div>

<div class="linkcontroller" divId="div1"></div>
```

CSS

```
.links {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.linkcontroller {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
if($('.linkcontroller').length){
  var divId= $(this).attr("divId");
$("#" + divId).hide();
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#'+$('.linkcontroller').attr('divId')).hide()
```

written in one line may cause some to question if it is 'simplified'.

The starting `if` is not needed - you'll just hide nothing if linkcontroller isn't present.

Comment: this is the best answer. and yes, you are correct is saying it is not simplified. my method of thinking was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Write `$('.linkcontroller')` instead of `$(this)`

Try:

```
if($('.linkcontroller').length> 0){
    var divId= $('.linkcontroller').attr("divId");  
    $("#" + divId).hide();
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/k43a8/1/)

Comment: that did it. thank you very much. i'm new to jquery so i'm still learning. amazing all the negative votes lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.linkcontroller').length) $("#" + $(".linkcontroller").attr("divId")).hide();
```

Simplified into 1 line!